# how do i draw a line on a form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

in vb.net i would like to draw a regular line on a form. is there a control to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way at design time is to use a Label control and set it's height, or width to
1 (2px and 3D border gives a nice chiseled effect). Or else you can manually draw using GDI:

```
Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
Dim formGraphics as System.Drawing.Graphics
formGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 200, 200)
myPen.Dispose()
formGraphics.Dispose()
```

Comment: I usually create a user control which does this.

Comment: What does the word "Me" mean? "Form" or some "User Control" ?

Answer (score 18):

What Mitch Wheat said is generally regarded as the correct answer, and what I have done in the past. However, if you want to have a visual control that you can drag on to a form, add the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPack to your visual studio toolbox. To do that right-click on toolbox select "Choose Items...". Locate "Line Shape" on the .Net Framework Components tab.

Comment: Will it require any dlls with compiled program?

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, New Point(0, Me.Height - 1), New Point(Me.Width, Me.Height - 1))
End Sub
```

This draws a line on the bottom of the control every time it is painted.